# If $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$, then $A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused trying proving this problem. I tried the following:

Suppose $A\neq B$, then $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)=\emptyset\implies \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) =\emptyset \implies A \cup B =\emptyset \implies A=B$, but this is a contradiction. Thus, $A = B$. The thing with this though is that I'm not quite sure about $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)=\emptyset$, because $A$ and $B$ can have a common element and still be different.

Comment: Note $A\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ etc.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)=\emptyset$  and $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)=\emptyset$ look strange to me, since I would have thought at least $\{\emptyset\}$ was a subset of each and  $\{\emptyset\} \not = \emptyset$. Then there is your point $A$ and $B$ may be different while having a non-empty intersection.  In fact $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ and if this is $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ then $A\cap B =A\cup B$ and so  $A=B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see.
$$\mathcal P(A\cup B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B).$$
In words: every subset of $A\cup B$ is a subset of $A$ and a subset of $B$ (and vice versa).

Well, $A$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ (you knew that, right?), so $A$ is a subset of $A$ (so what, we already knew that) and $A$ is a subset of $B$ (now we're getting somewhere).

We've shown that $A$ is a subset of $B$. The problem is half done, because to show that $A=B$ we just have to show that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$. I'll leave the other half to you.

Comment: Thanks! The idea is so clean, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any set $A$ we have that $A$ is the maximal element of $\mathcal P(A)$. So if the given property is true then any set in $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ (especially $A,B$) must be in $\mathcal P(A)$ and in $\mathcal P(B)$ and thus subsets of $A$ and of $B$. Thus $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

Also your prove is not correct. Even if $A,B$ are disjoint (which they do not need to by), the powersets share at least the $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be concerned about your assumption that if $A \neq B$, then $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \emptyset$. For example, if $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$, then $A \neq B$, but $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \{ \emptyset, \{2\}\}$. In fact $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$ always has $\emptyset$ as a member. (In general, $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$.)

To solve your problem, let's assume $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$. Then for any $a \in A$, we have: $$\{a\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$$ so $\{a\} \subseteq B$, which implies that $a \in B$. So $A \subseteq B$. Likewise starting with $b \in B$, our assumption gives us that $b \in A$, so that $B \subseteq A$. Hence our assumption implies that $A = B$.